# Get First VALUE

Tags: sql

I have table

```
ID     VALUE     DATE
1      2         1.1.2013 
1      3         1.9.2013
1      3         1.4.2013
2      1         1.1.2013 
2      1         1.2.2013
3      3         1.3.2013
3      1         1.4.2013
3      3         1.5.2013
```

I need to get only first value for id and only one row per id.

I try this select:

```
SELECT ID,
       first_value(VALUE) over(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY DATE) f_value,
       first_value(DATE) over(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY DATE) f_date
FROM table1
GROUP BY ID
```

But I cannot use GROUP BY with FIRST_VALUE.

Comment: First value in your case means the value with the earliest date?

Comment: Yes. Need to be a first value order by date group by id

Comment: I think you need `MIN(VALUE)`, `MIN(DATE)` if you want to return one row per id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID,
   first_value(VALUE) over(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY DATE) f_value,
   first_value(DATE) over(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY DATE) f_date
FROM table1
```

You don't need GROUP BY because there are already group by and order by in OVER function.

Comment: That is why I placed DISTINCT keyword. Without it you will have n same record for one ID

Comment: Sorry, didn't seen DISTINCT. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID,VALUE,DATE
FROM
--inline view will return the min date for each group based on ID
 (
   SELECT ID,
          value,
          date,
          MIN(DATE) over(PARTITION BY id) f_date
    FROM table1
  )
 WHERE f_date=date; --compare the date and fetch the row with min date
```